# get index of array with condition

Tags: php

I have this kind of array :

```
$arrVar = array(
    0 => array(
        'val'=> 9
    ),
    1 => array(
        'val'=> 12,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'val'=> 4
    ),
);
```

How do I make a function that returns the index of an array based on a variable $myVar?
For example :

if `$myVar = 4` the function will return `$arrVar['2']`

if `$myVar = 8` the function will return `$arrVar['2']`

if `$myVar = 10` the function will return `$arrVar['0']`

This is my array

```
$arrVar = array(
    0 => array(
        'qty'=>9,
        'disc'=> 0.15
    ),
    1 => array(
        'qty'=>12,
        'disc'=> 0.20
    ),
    2 => array(
        'qty'=>4,
        'disc'=> 0.10
    ),
);
```

- when customer A buy 4 products he will get disc 10%
- or when customer A buy 8 products he will get disc 10%
- or when customer A buy 10 products he will get disc 15%

Comment: Please clearify the logic. Why should $myvar = 8 return $arrVar['2']. That doesn't make any sense base on your sample. Do you have a better sample or real world context?

Comment: I understand the condition for when $myVar is 4. But what relationship is there for (8->4) and (10->9)? You don't ever show the key 9 in the example list of data.

Comment: $myvar = 8 return $arrVar['2'] because 8 is greater than 4 and less than 9
sorry for bad english... :)

Comment: sorry question updated .. if $myVar = 10 the function will return $arrVar['1']

Comment: I still struggle to understand what your question is. What have you tried so far to make this function?

Comment: I get the feeling that the OP wants to return the index of the entry which has the highest qty that is <= to his $myvar value, though I hope they will clarify

Comment: `if $myVar = 10 the function will return $arrVar['1']` then IMO if $myVar = 8 the function should return `$arrVar['0']` NOT `$arrVar['2']` as per your question. Please build the clear logic and update the question to get proper answers.

Comment: @anubhava, i've update the question.. tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following php function to calculate your **discount percentage**:

```
function searchArr($needle) {
   global $arrVar;
   $arr=array();
   foreach($arrVar as $key => $value) {
      $vals = array_values($value);
      $arr[$vals[0]] = $vals[1];
   }
   ksort($arr);
   $prev=0;
   foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      if ($needle < $key)
         return 100 * ($prev==0 ? $value : $prev);
      $prev = $value;
   }
   return 100 * $prev;
}
```

**TESTING:**

```
echo "Discount: " . searchArr(4)  . "%\n";
echo "Discount: " . searchArr(8)  . "%\n";
echo "Discount: " . searchArr(10) . "%\n";
echo "Discount: " . searchArr(12) . "%\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Discount: 10%
Discount: 10%
Discount: 15%
Discount: 20%
```

See this code running here: http://ideone.com/zLDen

Comment: i think the code is not working yet.. because when i try to  run searchArr(12), it doesnt work. it should be 20%. Please advise. thx anyway

Comment: @anubhava.. yes its working flawless... great code!!... thx a lot... :)